# near identity change of coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Problem: Consider the scalar differential equation

$$x'  = \frac{4x – 24x^2 – 16x^3}{1 – 12x – 12x^2}.$$

which has a fixed point at $x^*  = 0 $. For $x$ close to  $x^*  = 0 $ find a near identity change of coordinates $y = \phi(x) = x + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3 $ (i.e., find $b_2, b_2 ∈ R$) such that close to $y = 0 $ we have  $y'  = Df(x^*)y$.

I found $ Df(x^*)$, I substituted in $y'  = Df(x^*)y$, and I compared the coefficients in both sides, but the fraction made me confused. So could you help me guys to do this problem?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can go all the way and compute the coefficients, but I'll try to give a quicker argument.

First of all, I assume that $y=\phi(x)$ should read $y=\phi(x)=x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3$.

Next I assume that you already know that $Df(x^*)=4$. Which means that you are interested in solving:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}x' &=4(x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3)\\
(1+2b_2x+3b_3x^2)\frac{4x–24x^2–16x^3}{1–12x–12x^2} &= 4(x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3).
\end{eqnarray}

We can then rewrite as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
(1+2b_2x+3b_3x^2)\frac{4(x–6x^2–4x^3)}{1–12x–12x^2} &= 4(x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3)\\
(1+2b_2x+3b_3x^2)\frac{x–6x^2–4x^3}{1–12x–12x^2} &= (x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3).
\end{eqnarray}

In such format it is evident that the coefficients are: $b_2=-6$ and $b_3=-4$.